# How to visualise Matlab statement as a formula?

Tags: matlab

Suppose you have:

```
a = b/c;
```

Is there any toolbox or alternative editor that would allow you to visualise formulae in the way you would normally write them by hand? And if not is there any convenient way to implement this into some open source editor?

For example, LaTeX editors have such visualisation when you hover over the equation.

Such things exist for Excel also:
[fxRender](https://www.codecogs.com/fxRender)

Comment: You can use the `latex` command to convert a symbolic math formula to LaTeX. Just don't expect it to figure out the nicest/cleanest way to convert math to markup. There's also `pretty`.

Comment: You can also use `pretty` just for readable view of symbolic variables

Comment: Convert to latex then use there - not very elegant and convenient. "Pretty" in my opinion should be called Ugly. Thanks for the comments.